# Connecting to multiple databases using same JDBC drivers performance

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, database-performance, executor

I have a requirement to write a java application (web based) that will connect to an Oracle 11G databases (currently is connecting 10-12 different oracle databases), read some data from it (all are select queries).

After iterating this arraylist, I am connecting each database, fire select query (same query I am firing for all databases), get record , put it in one global collection list and close connection and continuing same process over this loop.

Currently I am "Executors" to connect multiple databases.
again using  `ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);`
give one surprise to me. for creting first database connection, it shows immediate log, but for subsequent database connection, it prints logs after 60 seconds, so i am not getting why this is taking 60 secs or more for all connections?
 logically, it should take time for all connections as like one.

Please suggest performance improvement for this application.

Comment: You should use Connection pooling. If you are not running in a server environment look for open source solutions like [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) or [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/)

Comment: Are the connections opened by the worker threads or by the main threads? Why is openConnection synchronized? In which class is it located?

Comment: Currently i am running this application using JSF 2.0 (for UI) and tomcat as server.

Comment: Since you are running in a server you can configure a `DataSource` which you can then get from your server using a JNDI lookup. See an [example for Oracle](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. but in DataSource, i have to write URL of database to be connected. But i am taking all DB information from xml file. and its dynamic information maintained in XML file.

Comment: connections are opened by worker threads. Now i have removed opnConnection as syncronized. Threads are located in backing bean class and openConnection methos is present in DAO layer class.

Answer (score 0):

Opening a database connection is an expensive operation; if possible you should connect to each database once and reuse the connection for all queries made to that database (also known as connection pooling). It's not clear if this is what you're already doing.

Another thing that seems strange is that you have made the openConnection method synchronized. I see no need for doing that, and depending on how your code is structured it may mean that only one thread can be opening a connection at a given time. Since connecting takes a long time you'd want each thread to make its connection in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for this valuable suggestion. I will remove "synchronized" for openConnection method. Hope it will gain me some performance improvement. and Another thing that, i am already reusing connection made to that database.

Comment: I have checked by removing  "synchronized" for openConnection method, but not satisfied with performance.No any improvement :(

Comment: You haven't answered my questions so it's impossible to suggest anything. Anyway it's hard to detect the bottle neck of a system with no access to it or knowledge about how everything fits together so you'll unlikely get a satisfactory answer to this question

Comment: Sorry for late answer.connections are opened by worker threads. Now i have removed opnConnection as syncronized. Threads are located in backing bean class and openConnection methos is present in DAO layer class.

Comment: connections are opened by worker threads. Now i have removed opnConnection as syncronized. Threads are located in backing bean class and openConnection methos is present in DAO layer class.